# NameError: undefined local variable or method 'user' for UserTest using minitest with factory_bot_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, minitest

I have a `:user` defined in my factory, but `build`, `create`, and `build_stubbed` for some reason throw an undefined variable method. I am using minitest and factory_bot_rails.

Here's my test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < Minitest::Test
 def setup
  user = FactoryBot.create(:user)
 end

 def test_valid_setup
  assert_equal user.firstname = "ss"
 end
end
```

And here's my factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
 factory :user do
    email Faker::Internet.email
    firstname "ss"
    lastname Faker::Name.last_name
    username Faker::Pokemon.name
    website Faker::Internet.domain_name
 end
end
```

I also have this in my test_helper:

```
class Minitest::Unit::TestCase
 include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods
end
```

My error output is:

```
Error:
UserTest#test_valid_setup:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `user' for #<UserTest:0x007fe1e87d9908> 
test/models/user_test.rb:9:in `test_valid_setup'
```

What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `@user` for my variable and replacing the `=` in `assert_equal user.firstname = "ss"` with a `,` fixed the problem. According to the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/minitest/unit/rdoc/MiniTest/Assertions.html), this method expects 2 - 3 arguments.

The correct syntax is

```
def test_valid_setup
 assert_equal @user.firstname, "ss"
end
```